# How to create Windows like taskbar toolbar to access desired folder and subfolder fast?

Tags: taskbar, tools

Please see image below:

[image]

[image]

Is there any application for Ubuntu which can give this facility?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I recall seeing an ubuntu menu indicator, don't know if it is still maintained for recent releases.

Comment: You can see the menu indicator mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called LauncherFolders (see the linked article for information) that should work. I've used it and it works wonderfully.

http://www.noobslab.com/2014/09/install-launchfolders-for-unity.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andrew. But with launcherfolders I can create drawer. It doesn't browse subfolders and subfolders inside the subfolders and so on with just mouse over, as we do in windows taskbar toolbar as we can see in the image above. I need to browse specific subfolders fast and frequntly.

Comment: I'm afraid i haven't found anything like that yet. I will look for something to help you.

Comment: This article might help: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-ubuntu-unity-launcher-gets-a-facelift-with-unity-drawers/

Comment: It seems it is not exactly the thing what I need. But still at this moment it is helpful, I will give it a try. I can carry on my work with this. Thank you for the article link @Andrew